# Managing my URL for my 2013 SharePoint site

Tags: 2013, site-collection

I am reading about SharePoint 2013, but I got confused on what are the major differences when building the following in respect to the URL that will be produced:-

1. Site
2. Site Collection
3. Sub sites

Now when I want to create new site collection I have to specify its URL, which will be constructed as follow:-

Hostname + Drop down list + [text to enter]

If I can create new site collection I have to show from a drop down list so this means that site collection should exists below a site? And when building a sub site instead of a site collection what the URL will be?
BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you will create a web application with URL looking like this, (HostName as referenced by yourself)

```
portal.companyName.com //we call it host header, this URL looks like a intranet
www.companyName.com //if its going to be a public site
```

Then you create Managed paths, which you referenced as Drop Down List in your question.

I just found this picture will help you understand better,

[image]

> Managed paths, well, manages the paths. That might sound a bit funny,
>   but it’s true. Within SharePoint, you cannot create a site collection
>   just anywhere you want. You have to attach a site collection to a
>   managed path.
>
> The biggest benefit of doing this is that it helps keep SharePoint
>   manageable from the user’s perspective. You don’t want site
>   collections to be created haphazardly. There should be some logic
>   applied to the structure. In highly structured environments, a
>   SharePoint steering committee can specify the managed paths that
>   should be used. Policies then prohibit the addition of new managed
>   paths without committee approval.
>
> When administrators create new site collections, they are unable to
>   create them outside of where the managed paths define.

[Source](http://www.petri.co.il/understanding-managed-paths-sharepoint-2010.htm#)

> I have to show from a drop down list so this means that site
>   collection should exists below a site?

You need to create a managed path for the site collection, however you can create a root site collection though, e.g. in above picture you can create your site collection at `HTTP://SharePoint.contoso.com/clients`

> Explicit Inclusion:
>
> When we are not planning to create further site collections under a
>   specified managed path, then we use this option. Explicit Inclusion
>   Managed paths allows in creation of only one site collection at the
>   exact given URL. In our case fahadexplicit would be the only site
>   collection that can be created. SharePoint will allow creating only
>   one site collection within this Managed Path.
>
> The URL would be: `http://servername:port/fahadexplicit`
>
> Wildcard Inclusion:
>
> When we want to create more than one site collection under a specific
>   managed path, we use this option. Wildcard Inclusion Managed Paths
>   allow unlimited site collection to be created under a given URL. In
>   our case under fahadwildcard, we can create any number of site
>   collections.
>
> The URL of these site collections would be as below:
>
> ```
>  http://servername:port/fahadwildcard/sitecolelction1
>  http://servername:port/fahadwildcard/sitecolelction2
>  http://servername:port/fahadwildcard/sitecolelction3
>  http://servername:port/fahadwildcard/sitecolelction4
> ```

[Source](http://www.sharepointpitstop.com/2012/11/managedpath-explicit-wildcard-inclusions.html)

Comment: thanks for the reply. YOU SAID "In above picture you can create your site collection at HTTP://SharePoint.contoso.com/clients". But as i understand it; i can only define a site collection on the root of a managed path Only if i create an explicit managed path ? am i right?

Comment: yes, with explicit managed path, you can only have 1 site collection. check updated answer.