# How to restore root Web application as Site collection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have created root web application in my development machine. Now I want to restore this web application to the site collection on the UAT server

Is it possible to backup the root web application and restore it again to the site collection under a different web application?

Comment: What do you mean with root web application? Is it multiple site collections or just one?

Comment: Are you using SharePoint 2010 or 2013?

Answer (score 5):

**Moving site collection ?**

If you want to move site not delete it then follow answers in this post [Moving a site to a different site collection](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/40912/moving-a-site-to-a-different-site-collection)

> is it possiable to back the root web application and restore it again
> to the site collection under diffrent web application ?

As far as I understood, i believe you created a root site collection not root web application, you can delete the site collection from central admin or using Powershell script and create a new root site collection or can use [Managed Path](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261845.aspx) for creating site collection.

Also this answer of mine for clear understand of how urls are structured in SP [Managing my URL for my 2013 SharePoint site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/66710/managing-my-url-for-my-2013-sharepoint-site)

For moving web applications you will need to go through lot depending on how customize is your sharepoint with custom developement but this post should put you towards right direction [Moving a Web Application from One server farm to another server farm](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53352/moving-a-web-application-from-one-server-farm-to-another-server-farm)

Comment: How is the part about deleting a site collection relevant to backup / restore of a site collection (possibly) to a different web application? :)

Comment: Yes, that could be something OP might be asking in first sentence of question :).

Comment: He wants to backup a site collection from Dev and restore it in UAT, not delete it

Answer (score -2):

Have you looked into Export / Import...?

Backup / Restore would be messy and cause problems down the line.

Ideally, this should be managed via SP features...deployments..

Comment: Care to share your experiences with the `messy` and `problems`?